# Присвоить ник клиенту на сервере WebSockets

Tags: javascript, массивы, websocket

Имеется сервер. На данный момент, каждому подключенному пользователю присваивается рандомный id,когда клиент отключается - его рандомный id удаляется с массива подключенных клиентов. Но, проблема заключается в том, что когда клиент либо подключается к серверу, либо напротив - отключается, необходимо отправлять данные об этом всем клиентам чтобы они получили сообщение "Клиент с ником Dima отключен от сервера". И вот здесь главный вопрос, как можно присвоить к этому рандомному id который определяется сразу при подключению к серверу еще и ник тот, который отправит пользователь? Тяжело сформировать вопрос, потому что не могу представить как это должно работать.

Нужно переопределить переменную id на ту, которую отправит клиент. Я бы хотел конечно сразу присваивать id, который отправит пользователь, но не знаю как сделать отправку на сервер до того момента, как определится переменная id, так как эта функция срабатывает сразу при соединении, именно поэтому решил сначала присваивать рандомный id, а потом уже переопределять. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

```
var clients = {}; //массив подключенных клиентов

webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

  var id = Math.random(); //клиенту присваивается рандомный id при подключении
  clients[id] = ws; //теперь клиент идентифицируется на сервере с этим id, а хотелось бы чтобы идентифицировался по нику
  console.log("новое соединение " + id);

  ws.on('message', function(login) { //здесь клиент передает информацию, в данном случае пользователь вводит какой-нибудь ник, нужно чтобы слово которое отправит пользователь было новым идентификатором, то есть нужно переопределить переменную id которая при коннекте с сервером была создана или как-то иначе, понятия не имею
    id = login; //пробовал так, но все равно остается тот, рандомный id который определился здесь " var id = Math.random();"

});
});
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Если что-то с вопроса не непонятно, напишите, постараюсь более подробно описать.

Comment: Вы бы свои предыдущие свои вопросы проверяли. Точнее ответы на них)

Comment: После успешного соединения отправлять серверу идентификационное сообщение с информацией о клиенте. На сервере хранить не массив соединений с непонятными ид, а массив объектов, в которых будет информация о клиенте. По идее как-то так.

Comment: информацию то я отправляю, но вот вопрос в том, как на сервере ее присвоить.

Comment: Нашел решение. Создал отдельный массив который хранит ники клиентов, ключ массива - id клиента, а значение - ник.

Comment: @Евгений Калайда это решение требует напряжения мысли всего сообщества инета...и вы спасли это сообщество от краха :)